# How can I completely disable my AppleID from receiving iMessages?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro and an Android phone. I signed into iCloud and Messages on mac with my AppleID. I then sent a message to my colleague, using Messages app, he responded.
I then unchecked 'Enable iMessages in iCloud' and signed out of my Messages app. I'm not logged in anywhere but my friend can still send iMessages to my AppleID, even though I am not signed it anywhere else and iCloud for iMessages is not enabled. The messages of course are not delivered, but why is he able to send them at all and how to disable it completely?

Is the fact that my appleID is used for iMessages cached on his phone? on the server? How long will it wait before realizing iMessage is not an option?

I do not want to use iMessage on Mac at all, where will his messages end up? And how soon will he know the delivery failed?

I'm surprised to learn it's not immediate after signing out of the account.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something I've ever tested, but you probably ought to have unchecked the others too…
Enable this account & You can be reached for messages as

[image]

You can disable a phone number previously registered even if you don't have a Mac or iPhone -  [Apple - Deregister iMessage](https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage/)

Comment: Under 'You can be reached' -the checkboxes are greyed out, I cannot uncheck them. I do not have 'Enable this account checkbox'. Running Monterrey.

Comment: Hmm… yeah, that seems to be gone in Big Sur too. Sorry, I've no idea where they moved it to:\